# Migration of Lua REST microservice to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, lua, aws-lambda, serverless

On my project I have few microservices written on Lua which are hosted on Heroku. Currently we are migrating to AWS and as part of that migration we are looking for ways how easier to migrate our Lua services. I know that we could take usual EC2 for that purpose, but I'd like to try find some more cost-effective solutions.

As AWS Lambda by default does not supports Lua language for writing functions I'm interested in what's the easiest way to migrate my existing Lua services to Lambda? Maybe does it make sense try to run it on some of JVM implementation for Lua (like [luaj](https://github.com/luaj/luaj) or [Rembulan](https://github.com/mjanicek/rembulan)) or it will be better just rewrite our services on something what's supported by AWS Lambda (like Python or Go)?

Comment: You could include the files you need in your zip then trigger them from a supported language. You can run whatever you want in Lambda.

Comment: @Adam How can I run Lua script in AWS Lambda if it don't supports Lua? Lambda provides support of limited set of languages as i see from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lua bindings from some other language.
Nice approach we tried was using Rust bindings (https://github.com/kyren/rlua) and AWS also supports Rust runtime (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/rust-runtime-for-aws-lambda/)